# Cannot Open Excel sheet in web-browser

Tags: error, excel

I am having a problem opening the excel sheet in web browser, it throws an exception..

> Excel Web Access >> An error has occurred.
>
> Please contact your system administrator if this problem persists.>>

On checking I saw the indexing services and Search services are not running, but they are not starting too, exception handle 10.. please guide if i am missing something. Also SSP creation is not helping as it requires these services to run.

Comment: which browser you are using, also can you check is SharePointAddin is installed on your browser ?